# How do I extract specific URLs from an HTML file

Tags: search

I have an HTML file, without any formatting. I want to extract URLs of the form https://sitename.com/*/ending and only those URLs.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

This question is NOT a duplicate. The other question is asking about pulling the contents of a specific named DIV. This is asking how to pull a list of URLs, fitting a specific format.

Comment: No. That's not really enough to answer my question. How would I use a selector to select only URLs of a given format?

Comment: The only difference is you want the URL: the approach is exactly the same...

Comment: Okay. So once again, how do I select URLs of a given format?!

Comment: You follow the directions in the answer to the duplicate... Of course, some independent thought is required.

Comment: Sorry that I lack the knowledge of the tool in order to perform the task. Your comments are not constructive. #divname is easy enough. How do I say "just URLs" and then filter out URLs that are not of the proper form?

Comment: I find the easiest way to extract URLs from HTML files is to use a tool like `lynx` that already knows how to identify and extract URLs.  e.g. `lynx -dump -listonly file.html | awk '/https:\/\/sitename\.com\//  {print $2}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple grep should do this for you:

```
grep -o "https://sitename.com/.+/ending" somefile.html
```

(Note: I don't have a *nix machine in front of me right now to test this on.)

Edit: Fired up my linux box and found this to work:

```
grep -wEo "https://sitename\.com/[^/]+/ending" somefile.html
```

A `.+` will be greedy and capture way too much.  Using a negative assertion will properly find the end of a sub-directory.  Note this will NOT find nested sub-directories such as `https://sitename.com/sub/directory/ending`.

Comment: grep -o "https://sitename.com/" somefile.html I get a bunch of lines of that string, but if I add in the rest, I get nothing.

Comment: Try `egrep` (or `grep -e`) instead.

Comment: No go. Good try though. I think I'm getting somewhere. The issue, I think, is that these URLs are not necessarily on separate lines.

Comment: Whoops - forgot you will also have to escape some stuff...
    grep -eo "https:\/\/sitename\.com\/.+\/ending" somefile.html

Comment: grep: https:\/\/sitename\.com\/.+\/ending: No such file or directory
test.html:https://sitename.com/test-1/ending https://sitename.com/test-2/ending
test.html:https://notsite.com/ending

Comment: It's a good effort. Maybe wait until you're in front of a terminal?

Comment: Damn my curiosity!  Fired up my Linux boxxen and came up with this one which appears to work: `grep -wEo "https://sitename\.com/[^/]+/ending" somefile.html`  I had also forgotten about regex being greedy, so we use a negated character class to match the middle part of the URL.  Note that this will NOT match a URL such as "https://sitename.com/sub/directory/ending"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36560/discussion-between-hobadee-and-vasshu).